# Wordpress custom plugin open a page

Tags: php, wordpress, backend, admin

I will try to explain it this way: I am developing my own custom post type plugin. So I have a menu on the admins page to create different post types (News, Jobs, Media...).

adding the menu:

```
add_menu_page('Post Type Page', 'Posting', 'manage_options', 'posting', 'posting','dashicons-groups', $position ='4');
    
add_submenu_page( 'posting', 'News','News','manage_options', 'news_list', 'post_news');
    
add_submenu_page( 'posting', 'Jobs','Jobs', 'manage_options', 'jobs_list', 'post_job');
.....
```

If the admin clicks now News menu item, I want a page to open with a button on top 'create new News' and than a list of all created news.

If the admin clicks Jobs menu item, I want a page to open with a button on top 'create new Job' and than a list of all created jobs.

this is the code:

```
    function post_news(){

        echo 'News';
    
        echo '<form id="post" method="POST" action=""><br><br><button class="button" name="create_posting">Create new News</button><br><br><input name="post_type" type="hidden" value="news"></form>'; 
    
        echo get_posting_list('news');      
}
```

So far everythibg works.

Now I want to create different template pages to create the post (different data for Jobs than for News).

If the admin clicks the 'create new News' button I want a new page to open with the form to create a news post. And if he clicks 'create new Jobs' button the template for jobs should open. But in the menu on the left side the menu item 'News' or 'Jobs' has to stay active. So only the content has to change.

The templates are saved in the folder 'pages' in the plugin folder.

How can I make this?

Comment: Your form has `action=""`, so it submits against the current URL. And `add_submenu_page` configures whether a certain page should be shown in a _menu_, based on the current user's capabilities. That has no relation to what happens when your form gets submitted.

Comment: ok, but what is the solution for this problem? How should I do it?

Comment: I don't even get what you mean by _"open a template page"_.  Can you add a proper explanation of what you are actually trying to _achieve_? _"The template page is in the subfolder: my_plugin/page/post_news.php"_ - and it is supposed to do what, exactly? You should rather not _link_ to any files contained in your plugin folder directly. Whatever this is _supposed_ to do, probably involves _embedding_ this template in some other context.

Comment: I chaned the explanation of the question. I hope now the problam is described better.

Comment: So if everything works with your `post_news()` function - then create a counterpart `post_jobs()` then? _"But in the menu on the left side the menu item 'News' or 'Jobs' has to stay active."_ - are you saying that wasn't automatically the case, when you added them via `add_menu_page`/`add_submenu_page`?

Comment: what I meant was, that I dont want to open onother page. I want to stay on the opened page load the content of the template (create new job) into the active page. But the old content (the button and the list with posts) has to be removed somehow.

Comment: But _why_ would you want that? The mechanism you are using is explicitly meant to add _different_ pages to the admin menu. Sounds like you are trying really hard to work against the system here.

Comment: How would I have to do it if I want to stay in the same menu? Is there a well explained example?